# REST API Base64 image imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Tags: php, json, base64, gd

I am developing a REST API to an Android App. I want to save a base64 image as a jpeg image that sending from the App. I wrote a code to that with laravel intervention and tested with postman. No Problem. But when data is sending from the Android App, They said me they got 500 error with a message `Image intervention - Image source not readable`.

After that I saw their JSON contains backslashes and `\n`s. So I have tried to escape them with `stripslashes`, `stripcslashes`, `utf8_encode` , `utf8_decode` but no luck.

After I have left the laravel intervention and start to try with `imagecreatefromstring` (gd) library. Also no luck with `imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format` message.

Here  is my try.

```
<?php
$json_string = '{"id_city":2,"image":"UklGRpQEAABXRUJQVlA4IIgEAAAQGgCdASpyAHMAPxF+tlMsKCUiqxLrCYAiCWkRQAHDhsYwTe19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\nUDgX+FGlCdz94\/3XNLPbe\/kEpZ\/5C+QJJVAV27kOIl9IC8If9YGAAA==\n"}';

$data = json_decode($json_string);

var_dump($data->image);
// After copy and pasted the var_dump result to the postman it works

$base64_decoded = base64_decode($data->image);

imagecreatefromstring($base64_decoded);
?>
```

Comment: Does it work with `imagecreatefromwebp` since your file is webp?

Comment: Thanks @Scuzzy . You are a brilliant. I have spent 2 days to fix it. You fixed it with one second. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer. I can hit green button.

Comment: You could check that when `imagecreatefromstring` returns false, try `imagecreatefromwebp` after, so you can support more formats automatically. The first thing I did was write your base64'ed content to disk to see what type of file it was first before I wrote any code, and _irfanview_ told me it was labeled wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Base64'ed data is actually a `.webp` image, but the [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function doesn't detect this encoding.

Change:

```
imagecreatefromstring(
```

To:

```
imagecreatefromwebp(
```

Comment: imagecreatefromwebp() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

Comment: @SobinAugustine write it to a temp file first: `$file = tmpfile(); file_put_contents( $file, $string ); $image = imagecreatefromwebp ( $file );`

Comment: I don't have any of this in all my base code. I don't know where is it.